# Boost rare results in solr

Tags: solr

In a collection there are several different categories of documents. I want the highest ranked search results to be the documents from categories where, for the specific query, there are fewest matching documents.

###### Concrete example

Let the categories be "foo", "bar", and "baz". If I were to search for "Fred", faceted by category, I would get back the following counts:

- foo: 17
- bar: 1
- baz: 201312

I want to construct a search and/or configure the index such that the one match from the "bar" category would be top of the search results, the 17 "foo" matches would be next, and finally the "baz" matches.

One way I think I could do this would be *first* to do a faceted search to get the count of matching documents in each category, and *then* do a *second search* with boosts based on the category counts - something along the lines of `bq=category:bar^10000&bq=category:foo^100`; the boosts of 10000 and 100 would obviously be derived from the facet counts and inserted into the query.

I would like to know if something roughly equivalent to this could be achieved in a more efficient way using only a single query, i.e. avoiding the need for a pre-query to fetch the facet counts.

Comment: I haven't been able to think of any built-in way to solve this, so your solution seems like a decent enough way to do it - as long as the number of categories is low-ish enough; it would just be two queries and performance should be OK, depending on the number of boosts you have to attach